# Docker - Error: adduser: The UID 0 is already in use

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I'm running docker compose, I'm getting this error:

```
adduser: The UID 0 is already in use.
ERROR: Service 'project-be' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c adduser -u ${UID} --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My Docker version is 19.03.6.

Any suggestion is welcome, thaks a lot

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  (You shouldn't usually need to manually specify the uid of the non-root container user.)

Answer (score 0):

I try to guess you (missing) docker file:

```
FROM some_image

# ...

RUN adduser -u ${UID} --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser

# ...
```

The docker build, unless specified by the image your inheriting from, runs under the `root` account, then the `UID` value is `0`. So you cannot create another user with the same ID.

Are you trying to create a root user? If the answer is yes, you should create a new user, then give it root grants.

```
FROM some_image

# ... 

RUN adduser appuser
RUN usermod -aG sudo appuser

# ...
```

Please tell me if I missed something.